# Use multiple button on same function of javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to make multiple button for different text boxes that uses the same function but store on different id names.

```
Name<input id="name"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Start</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var recognition = new (window.SpeechRecognition || 
        window.webkitSpeechRecognition || window.mozSpeechRecognition || 
        window.msSpeechRecognition)();
        recognition.lang = 'en-US';
        recognition.interimResults = false;
        recognition.maxAlternatives = 5;
        recognition.start();
        recognition.onresult = function(event) {
           document.getElementById("name").value =(event.results[0][0].transcript);
         };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Store the id into a data-*  attribute in a button, then read the value of the attribute in the function instead of hardcoding the id.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the ID of input field when calling the function, like this

```
Name<input id="name"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction('name')">Start</button>

Phone<input id="phone"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction('phone')">Start</button>


<script>
function myFunction(id) {
    var recognition = new (window.SpeechRecognition || 
        window.webkitSpeechRecognition || window.mozSpeechRecognition || 
        window.msSpeechRecognition)();
    recognition.lang = 'en-US';
    recognition.interimResults = false;
    recognition.maxAlternatives = 5;
    recognition.start();
    recognition.onresult = function(event) {    
         document.getElementById(id).value =(event.results[0][0].transcript);
    };
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am glad I was able to help. Please accept the answer so others can learn too.